# Unique Name For Dynamically Created Form Element

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dynamic

A few questions on here touch on similar subjects, but none I could find addressed my specific case.

I have a script that dynamically creates an `input[type="text"]` field and an `input[type="radio"]` field. I would like the created fields to generate unique names up to the max of 6 added fields. How can I do this with jQuery? How can i reference these newly created unique names in the PHP for my form?

jQuery:

```
var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<input type="radio" name="attend" id="attendC" value="cere" />
<input type="radio" name="attend" id="attendR" value="rece" />
<input type="radio" name="attend" id="attendB" value="both" />
<input type="radio" name="attend" id="attendN" value="neit" />
');
}
});
```

Comment: php is server side, jQuery is client side. Generate the id's server side with php and then use them as id's in your javascript `<input type=text" name="name" id="<?php echo json_encode($name_variable); ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is so many options for that. But the best thing you will do is :

Your unique id must be timestamp you can get it like this :

```
var uniqueId = Date.now() | 0;
```

So you should generate an array for all of these what i mean is :

```
var insertedIds = [];
```

That array will keep your inserted ids and should be passed to PHP in POST operation, so your code will be :

```
var x = 1;
var insertedIds = [];
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++;
        uniqueId = Date.now() | 0;
        $(wrapper).append('
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            <input type="radio" name="'+uniqueId+'_col0" id="attendC" value="cere" />
            <input type="radio" name="'+uniqueId+'_col1" id="attendR" value="rece" />
            <input type="radio" name="'+uniqueId+'_col2" id="attendB" value="both" />
            <input type="radio" name="'+uniqueId+'_col3" id="attendN" value="neit" />
        ');
        insertedIds.push(uniqueId);
    }
});
```

If you are not using AJAX for posting variables to PHP you can use it like this :

```
$("yourSubmitButton").click(function(){
    $("yourForm").append("<input type='hidden' name='insertedIds' value='"+JSON.stringify(insertedIds)+"'/>");
});
```

If you are using AJAX you can use this like this :

```
$.ajax({
    //url,type staff etc.
    data:"insertedIds="+JSON.stringify(insertedIds) // and other data
});
```

So that means you can fetch *id*_col0,*id*_col1... in PHP safely.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the same variable x or another global one:

```
var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('\
           <input type="text" name="name_0_"' + x + 'id="name"/>\
           <input type="radio" name="attend_1_"' + x + 'id="attendC" value="cere" />\
           <input type="radio" name="attend_2_"' + x + 'id="attendR" value="rece" />\
           <input type="radio" name="attend_3_"' + x + 'id="attendB" value="both" />\
           <input type="radio" name="attend_4_"' + x + 'id="attendN" value="neit" />\
       ');
    }
});
```

In this way in PHP you have only to check the first part of the name while the last part (from _number_number) is for grouping.

Comment: I used this method, however it took me a bit to figure out that your concatenation syntax is wrong. It should be `<input type="radio" name="attend'+x+'" id="attend'+x+'" value="rece" />`. The name of each radio button needs to be the same. Thanks for getting me started though. Upvoted